# Does installing Android OS onto Gear Neo disable some sensors?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors, tizen

I have a Gear Neo that I want to use for an Android Wear Prototype. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Epx4NMfUmIU to instal the OS and I successfully deployed my application and all is well. I checked the built in apps and the heart rate app works fine (even the heart rate sensor in the back lights up in green)

I tried implementing my own heart rate sensing app but the SensorManager says the heart rate sensor is null. I iterated over all available sensors and printed to the log and there were so many but the heart rate sensor was not there.

Any idea why that could be so?

Comment: have you tried the online sample app for Heart Rate Sensor from Tizen IDE? If that's working then it might be problem with your code.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but since it's tizen and I have changed the OS of the watch, would it work?

Comment: I would suggest you to try that sample app and then you can sure the OS and device are working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the required permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Yep, BODY_SENSORS is permitted.